# Force recompilation of certain files in rails assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm using ruby on rails 4.1.9.

Is there a way to define a whitelist of files that should be recompiled anytime, even if they don't change?

For example: I have a few `.js.erb` files injected with some Rails variables. So, even if the original file is not changing, they need recompilation.

Comment: Ever find a way to do this? I need the same thing